# An upper bound on an invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, norms

I have looked through books such as Matrix Analysis by R.A. Horn and C.R. Johnson and would not find an answer to the following question:

Given $V^TV \in S^{n}$, where $V$ is an invertible matrix with each column of $V$ of unit length. Can the norm of $(V^TV)^{-1}$ be bounded above by a constant that does not depend on the given matrix $V$?  If not, please provide an upper bound in terms of $V$?

Comment: The norm of $(V^TV)^{-1}$ is the inverse square of the smallest singular value $s_d(V)$ of $V$. There is no uniform lower bound on $s_d(V)$. I guess $s_d(V)^{-2}$ is not only an upper bound in terms of $V$, but actually the value. Or maybe you want an upper bound in some special form?

Comment: Yes, if the norm is the spectral norm, then $s_d(V)^{-2}$ is the value of the norm.  Given that each column of $V$ is of unit length, I wonder whether there is an uniform upper bound?  Or is it wishful thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the quantity you want is $\sigma_{\min}(V)^{-2}$, the inverse square of the minimum singular value of $V$.

Unfortunately you can't get any meaningful bound from below for matrices with unit column norms, as they can still be arbitrarily close to singular. For instance,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \cos \alpha \\
0 & \sin \alpha \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has a singular value that must tend to $0$ when $\alpha \to 0$.